# How can I modify admin bar only if my plugin is loaded

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin-bar

If I want to *always* change the admin toolbar at the top of the page it's easy.

```
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'add_toolbar_items', 100);
function add_toolbar_items($admin_bar){
  $admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'id'    => 'my-item',
    'title' => 'My Item',
    'href'  => '#',
    'meta'  => array(
        'title' => __('My Item'),            
    ),
  ));
}
```

No problem.
I want to add something to the top of the page, but only when we are on my plugin page.

So I want to do something like this:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');
function my_plugin_menu(){
  //We add the hook for our menu item on the main menu
  $main = add_menu_page( 'My Swell Plugin', 'My Swell Plugin', 'edit_posts', 'blah', 'generate_main_page',,__FILE__));
}
function generate_main_page(){
  //We are definitely in our plugins page now - let's modify the admin toolbar.
  add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'add_toolbar_items', 100);
  require_once('mainwindow.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember screen id of your page and check current screen id before adding new menu item:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );
function my_plugin_menu() {
    global $my_swell_plugin_page;
    $my_swell_plugin_page = add_menu_page( 'My Swell Plugin', 'My Swell Plugin', 'edit_posts', 'blah', 'generate_main_page' );
}

function generate_main_page() {
    //We are definitely in our plugins page now - let's modify the admin toolbar.
}

add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'add_toolbar_items', 100 );
function add_toolbar_items( $admin_bar ) {
    global $my_swell_plugin_page;

    if ( $my_swell_plugin_page == get_current_screen()->id ) {
        $admin_bar->add_menu( array(
            'id' => 'my-item',
            'title' => 'My Item',
            'href' => '#',
            'meta' => array(
                'title' => __( 'My Item' ),
            ),
        ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `$current_screen` object can help you:

```
global $current_screen;
if ( $current_screen->base == 'toplevel_page_blah' ){
    add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'add_toolbar_items', 100);
}
```

I haven't tested it but it should do the trick.